# How can I bind a property to a TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I know, maybe it is a simple question, bu I don't know how to realiza this:

I have my xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/conTgo;component/resources/images/bg_settings.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VersionNumber}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" FontSize="26.667" TextAlignment="Center" LineHeight="16"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

In my code behind I have:

```
 public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
```

How can I realise this?

Comment: Although the option explained in the answer below works, it may have long term maintainability issues. I recommend you read a little bit about the MVVM pattern and how to apply on Windows Phone: http://www.bing.com/search?q=MVVM+Windows+Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVVM pattern is highly recommended for Silverlight development and works well for cases like this as well as setting your code up better for unit testing.

However, If your property that your binding to resides directly in your control and you want to keep it there then your control will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order for the property to hook into Silverlight's (or WPF's) change notification:

```
public class YourControl : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string VersionNumber {
        get { return versionNumber; }
        set {
            versionNumber = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("VersionNumber");
        }         
    }
    private string versionNumber;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I would definitely recommend a MVVM approach however.

Comment: Although this gets the work done, I do not think that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a control and setting itself as the data context is a good idea. The template binding mechanism is intended for the control template structure to bind properties to its own control property values. INotifyPropertyChanged and DataContext are intended to export external data into the view. This is recommending the use of the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I get that Murven, and I plug MVVM whenever possible. To learn the absolute basics and see the change notification process working for this specific example my answer is appropriate.

Comment: OK, that's cool. I just think it is important to write it explicitly, so that both the person making the question and other people searching the site do not think this is the only answer for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

The binding searches the property on your datacontext. So if you've added the property to your page, then you must set your page as it's own datacontext.

In your page's constructor, after the call to "InitializeComponent()", add:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

That should do the trick.

This method is fine for small apps. If you want to make bigger and more structured app, you might want to learn about the MVVM pattern.